# Assigning an object that is a foreign key via the constructor modifies primary key

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have two classes: `Patient` and `Country`. `Patient` contains a property `CountryOfOrigin`, of type `Country`. I have modeled this relationship like this:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Patient>().OneToOne<Country>(x => x.CountryOfOrigin);
        }
```

(One patient was born in one country)

Whenever I construct a new `Patient` I wish to assign it a `Country` as a CountryOfOrigin.

```
var country = (from c in db.Countries
               where c.Code.Equals(countryCode,
                   StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
               select c).First();

>> db.Patients.Add(new Patient(firstName, lastName, birthDate, country));
db.SaveChanges();
```

However, I get the following exception on the line marked with '>>'

> base  {"The property 'CountryId' on entity type
>   'SqlLitePlayground.DataAccess.Country' is read-only and so cannot be
>   modified or marked as modified."} System.SystemException
>   {System.NotSupportedException}

When debugging I notice the following: before the line that throws the exception `CountryId` (a property with a private setter, detected as the primary key by convention) is `1`. Once the exception is thrown `CountryId` is `-1`. Nowhere in my code I change the value of `CountryId` (which would also be impossible because of the private setter) so I assume this happens in the `DbSet` method `db.Patients.Add(...)` however I do not understand why, or how I can correct this behaviour.

My ultimate question is, (how) can I have foreign keys that are concrete objects instead of integer?

*Note that this is a toy project, getting to learn EF7, I do care about the data currently in the database, I just want to learn how to model certain scenarios.*

Comment: Doesn't `OneToOne` mean that it is not possible to have two patients from the same country?

Comment: You're absolutely right. It should be ManyToOne as seen from the country. However, the final problem seemed to be something else (see my own answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the end the problem was not where I expected it. I had defined a `private` parameterless constructor instead of a `protected` parameterless constructor. None of the MSDN samples (on EF6) mention this as their classes do not have a constructor (probably done to keep the code short).

This prohibited the entity framework to generate proxy classes. Some side effect of this was apparently setting Id to -1. Or maybe that was how the framework tried to warn me (next time please throw an exception ;) ).

A good reference that explains proxy classes and what rules are required for them to be generated:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx